# Android Wear setOnClickListener crash

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I am trying to program an application for my Sony Smartwatch 3, and have some beginner knowledge of Android programming. I have added a button to my application, and I am trying to wire up said button. Only problem is when I add the setOnClickListener, my application crashes and fails to load. When I remove the code indicated in between the two arrows, the application fires up, and the button is displayed and I can click it (of course nothing happens). So I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I've searched and searched and and found no answer unfortunately. Any help would be much obliged, and tips and tricks for android wear would be very awesome!

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear_start);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub)
        {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });
    Button startingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.starting_button);
--> startingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(WearStart.this, "You clicked it!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
--> });
```

activity_wear_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_wear_start"
app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_wear_start" tools:context=".WearStart"
tools:deviceIds="wear"></android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

rect_activity_wear_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".WearStart"
tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/start_button"
    android:id="@+id/starting_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Crash Log

```
01-01 22:35:50.587    8740-8740/petryszak.kyle.dash E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: petryszak.kyle.dash, PID: 8740
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{petryszak.kyle.dash/petryszak.kyle.dash.WearStart}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at petryszak.kyle.dash.WearStart.onCreate(WearStart.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5943)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Are you sure your startingButton id is correct? Are you sure its not `null` when you're trying to set OnClickListener? Pls paste your layout (activity_wear_start) and the crash log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `button's click event` inside the `onLayoutInflated()` method as

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            imageButton=(ImageButton)stub.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Haiii",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent toNext=new Intent(Home.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toNext);

                }
            });


        }
    });
}
```

And go through this [link](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/android-wear-docs/latest/android-wear-docs.pdf) .It will be very useful for Android wearable application development.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the link! Unfortunately i cant vote your answer up, but I do in my heart!

Comment: @Kyle you need 15 reputation to up vote.thanks for your comment